# iPhone mobile web app retina image replacement

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, web-applications

I am creating a web app to be accessed through any smartphone. I have the index.html file here:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/?hy2jttea705ukpw

I have 2 jQuery functions on it. One is to detect if it is an iPhone the user is viewing the web app through and comes up with a little bubble, detailing instructions to add it to the homescreen. The next is a script to replace images with the retina images in my root folder with "@2x" in the name.

This is my problem. It works SOMETIMES and it doesnt always find the retina images to replace the original. Any ideas?

You can view the project at [www.iammarksummerton.co.uk](http://www.iammarksummerton.co.uk) through an iPhone to see what I mean

Comment: I found this website to replace the non-retina images for the retina images. It can be found here: http://retinajs.com/

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your app in there and think I see the problem. Assuming the images which arent showing up are those with the @2x suffix in their name, the problem is they are returning 404 errors.
Its possible the images are innacessible due to something in the htaccess.
Its possible the path to those images is wrong
Its possible the images are simply not there

PLease check for that, and that may solve your issue

**IMPORTANT** With that said however, I'd advice abandoning using javascript to look for this retina images and instead going with a css route.  I love javascript, but its overkill for what you are trying to do.

Each of those images with the css class .heading could be drawn with code. I assure you it will make your app load faster as a bonus. This is how id replace that with css. I tried it and it looks exactly the same, but did not require images to be replaced.

```
 **The html would be something like for each of those heading divs**
 <p class="heading">Can I access your social media?</p>

 **The css would be like**

 .heading {
      min-height: 53px;
      border: solid 2px #FD8B25;
      border-radius: 5px;
      line-height: 53px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
       font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 13px;
      padding: 0 12px;}

  .heading:after {
      content: '▼';/*You can replace '▼' with url(path/to/image) if needed */
      float: right;
  }
```

This wont replace the image but will look ultra sharp as its code based. If you still want to change your images to sharper ones through css avoiding the slower overhead of javascript.  Use this...

```
  @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
      .myCSSClass {
           background:url('path/to/image');
           /*in the case of an image tag, add lots of padding margin so that original image is not visible*/
      }
  }
```

Hope this helps. To avoid this resolution issues, always try to use code over images if you see no issues with this. Only time I see this being an issue is if you must support old versions of IE, and you must keep every graphical element.  For image heavy websites, I usually avoid optimizing the images to be retina optimized.  Fast load time is sometimes more important than high resolution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear cut solution for responsive images at this time. [Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/) outlines a few of our options.

No matter which you choose *do not* serve 2x images to iPhones only. For one, not all iPhones have retina displays—second if you're trying to build something somewhat future-proof, you'd want to target pixel density, not one model of a phone. Other brands and operating systems will probably have high-DPI screens in the near future. In the end it will be less work for you.